# Get error number with oracle database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, oracle, codeigniter, error-handling

First of all sorry for my bad English..

I have this function in a model:

```
function insertUser($data){

$sql = "INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array(
    $data["uname"],
    $data["nome"],
    $data["dnuser"],
    $data["muser"],
    $data["fruser"],
    $data["cpuser"],
    $data["euser"],
    md5($data["passu"])
  ));

//return $this->db->_error_number();

}
```

I have one primary key and when data is correct the function works but when is inserted a duplicate key the function doesn’t work. But how can i know that? i mean how can i catch the error ORA-00001 ??

BTW the commented line doesn’t work..

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Is the leasing `_` needed in `->_error_number()`?

Comment: yes, the function is defined that way in oci_driver.php in system folder...

Comment: What kind of class is $this->db then? Or what framework are you using? Which framework/application does this system folder belong to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use try catch block...

```
function insertUser($data){

$sql = "INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try{
$this->db->trans_start();
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array(
    $data["uname"],
    $data["nome"],
    $data["dnuser"],
    $data["muser"],
    $data["fruser"],
    $data["cpuser"],
    $data["euser"],
    md5($data["passu"])
  ));
$this->db->trans_commit();
}
catch(Exception $ex){
$this->db->trans_rollback();
echo "Error:".$ex;
}
}
```

You can check the following article..

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: are you sure have tried those codes and get expected result? for me those codes didn't result anything.